# nginx map variable lookup based on url or hostname + uri (not hostname)

Tags: nginx

we run Magento and until date depending on the hostname a variable was set to decide which store to show. Example below.

```
map $http_host $storecode {
 domain.com store1_en;
 otherdomain.com store2_en;
}
```

Now new stores are set-up using the (2 character) languagecode like 'en', 'de' or 'fr' and url's become domain.com/en or otherdomain.com/fr.

For the above to work the map lookup should be altered and no longer should the host of servername be used, but rather the first part of the URL .... and also in the right order ....

**question:** How can this be achieved? Or has anyone done this before?

---

As a result the following mappping is what we are looking for

- domain.com/en => store1_fr
- domain.com => store1_en
- otherdomain.com => store2_en

Some ideas as a solution:

```
map $uri $storecode {
 ^domain.com/en.* store1_fr;
 ^domain.com.* store1_en;
 ^otherdomain.com.* store2_en;
}

map $http_host$uri $storecode {
 ^domain.com/en.* store1_fr;
 ^domain.com.* store1_en;
 ^otherdomain.com.* store2_en;
}
```

or I was thinking about a MAP within a MAP?

or capture the first two letters from the $uri (and only if it does have two letters to exclude other subdirectory requests ..)

Help appreciated

Comment: Your last example is exactly what you need. Just put ~ before ^ and it will work.

Comment: Like this? map $host$uri $storecode { - ^domain.com/en.* store1_fr; - ^domain.com.* store1_en;

Comment: Like this: `map $http_host$uri $storecode { ~^domain.com/en.* store1_fr; }`

Comment: And can one use both map commands directly after each other? It doesnt seem so: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30078679/nginx-conf-w-multiple-maps-to-same-variable