# nginx conf /w multiple map(s) to same variable

Tags: nginx

we have a multisite set-up and need to map domains and domains/subfolders to a variable. This way the programming knows which version to load.

We have stores that have separate domains and that can be captured by `$http_host` but also domain.com/-string-locale-here- and are captured by `$http_host$uri` and a match command

Somehow the below is not working. Can this be because there are two map commands, both mapping towards the same variable `$storecode`

Or what might be going wrong?

```
map $http_host $storecode {
 default dom_nl;
 domain.com dom_nl;
 domain.de dom_de;
 store.com str_de;
 }

map $http_host$uri $storecode { 
  ~^store.com/en.* str_en;
  ~^store.com/fr.* str_fr;
}
```

Answer (score 30, accepted):

When `default` is not specified in a map block, the default resulting value will be an empty string. So, in your case, whatever value `$storecode` is set with in the first map block, it is replaced with an empty string in the second one.

Since map variables are evaluated when they are used, you cannot set `$storecode` as the default value in the second map block, because that will cause an infinite loop.

So the solution is to introduce a temporary variable in the first map block and then use it as the default value in the second block:

```
map $host $default_storecode {
    default dom_nl;
    domain.com dom_nl;
    domain.de dom_de;
    store.com str_de;
}

map $host$uri $storecode {
    default $default_storecode;

    ~^store.com/en.* str_en;
    ~^store.com/fr.* str_fr;
}
```

Alternatively, you can merge these two map blocks into one:

```
map $host$uri $storecode {
    default           dom_nl;

    ~^domain.com.*    dom_nl;
    ~^domain.de.*     dom_de;

    ~^store.com/en.*  str_en;
    ~^store.com/fr.*  str_fr;
    ~^store.com.*     str_de;
}
```