# Nginx Multiple domains set redirect for specific domain

Tags: redirect, nginx

my nginx server supports multiple domains:

```
server {
    server_name
        domain1.com www.domain1.com
        domain2.com www.domain2.com
        domain3.com www.domain3.com
}
```

I would like to specify different redirection rules per domain, such as:

```
if ( $host ~ "domain1.com" ) {
   map $request_uri $redirect_uri {
       /about.html  /about-us
   }
}

if ( $host ~ "domain2.com" ) {
  map $request_uri $redirect_uri {
       /about.html  /contact-us
   }
}
```

nginx only allows `if` inside a `server` block and `map` outside of `server` block so i'm stuck, any ideas how to implement this?

Maybe i should include a redirections file per domain, something like:

```
$redirections_file = "redirections/" . $host;
if ( file_exists( $redirections_file ) ) {
   include $redirections_file;
}
```

this is not a valid nginx code of course, just pseudo code.

Comment: Move the map outside and i believe it should work

Comment: but `map` should be per-domain, not for all domains

Comment: You can do it based on two variables also. See this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30078679/nginx-conf-w-multiple-maps-to-same-variable